# Permission issue for read only users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, css, 2016

We have SharePoint Server Enterprise 2016 implemented with build version '16.0.4534.1000' (May 2017 CU) and have a custom master page for our portal. We are facing a strange issue where users granted with read permission has issues viewing custom CSS changes. Users with Design permissions can only see custom CSS changes like custom global navigation and custom quick launch.

The users with read permissions can see the links on global navigation and quick launch but can't see custom CSS changes applied to them.

Comment: Think that these users might not have read access to the custom css pages and other custom stuffs. can you please check if they have access?

Comment: Yes they have access to the SiteAssets folder where we have uploaded those custom CSS files. We even granted them full control over the SiteAssets folder but no luck.

Comment: Whether your master pages and custom css changes published? did you check whether it is major version? or still in draft or submitted mode/ approved mode?

Comment: Both master page and custom css file changes are published in major versions.